# Solana: Change owner of account

Tags: solana

I am currently experimenting a bit with Solana accounts and I am wondering if it is possible to change the owner of an account.

I am curious it is possible since the security of some programs are relying on this owner check, as explained [here](https://blog.neodyme.io/posts/solana_common_pitfalls#missing-ownership-check)

I am also looking into the [assign](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/389d78e4243cc567976b84a3126fdb19b186eac8/runtime/src/system_instruction_processor.rs#L114) function and on how it works, but I was not able to make it work yet.

Am I misunderstanding something or just was not able to make it work?

Here the Python code is used:

```py
tx = Transaction().add(
    create_account(CreateAccountParams(
        from_pubkey=attacker_keypair.public_key,
        new_account_pubkey=account_keypair.public_key,
        lamports=client.get_minimum_balance_for_rent_exemption(0)["result"],
        space=0,
        program_id=attacker_keypair.public_key,
    ))
)
send_and_confirm_tx(client, tx, attacker_keypair, account_keypair)

print('Sending 1st tx to program')
tx = Transaction().add(TransactionInstruction(
    keys=[
        AccountMeta(pubkey=account_keypair.public_key, is_signer=False, is_writable=False),    
    ],
    program_id=PROGRAM_ID,
))

send_and_confirm_tx(client, tx, attacker_keypair)

print('Sending 2nd tx to program')
tx = Transaction().add(assign(AssignParams(
    account_pubkey=account_keypair.public_key,
    program_id=attacker2_keypair.public_key
)))

send_and_confirm_tx(client, tx, account_keypair)
```

Error message is: `InvalidAccountForFee`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`account_keypair` was already assigned to `attacker_keypair`, so when you try to use it as the fee payer in `2nd tx`, the runtime yells at you, since `account_keypair` can only have its lamports reduced by the program living at `attacker_keypair`.  To quickly fix your current issue, you can do:

```
print('Sending 2nd tx to program')
tx = Transaction().add(assign(AssignParams(
    account_pubkey=account_keypair.public_key,
    program_id=attacker2_keypair.public_key
)))

send_and_confirm_tx(client, tx, attacker_keypair, account_keypair)
```

This will cause another problem however. `account_keypair` is already owned by `attacker_keypair`, so only a program deployed to `attacker_keypair` can reassign ownership of `account_keypair`.  You can read up more on the Solana Account model at: https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#ownership-and-assignment-to-programs

The part that's interesting to you is:

> The owner is a program id. The runtime grants the program write access to the account if its id matches the owner. For the case of the System program, the runtime allows clients to transfer lamports and importantly assign account ownership, meaning changing the owner to a different program id. If an account is not owned by a program, the program is only permitted to read its data and credit the account.

This means that to reassign ownership, you need to write an on-chain program that reassigns the ownership to `attacker2_keypair`, deploy it to `attacker_keypair`, and then send a transaction containing an instruction to `attacker_keypair`.

Here are some example programs that perform the `assign` on the `AccountInfo`: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/85a2e599bbbf3d51f201167f921718e52c7ce59f/programs/bpf/rust/realloc/src/processor.rs#L54

Comment: Thanks for the information. This is already very helpful, yet I can't figure out on how to do that. I wrote a program and deployed it locally. Then, I created an account, and assigned it to the program. But how is the program going to transfer the ownership?
I am creating an assign instruction and invoke the system program, but I can't make it work, since I get and error of `Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account`
Next try: I assigned the account to a pda and make and invoke_signed call, but this leads to `signer privilege escalated`.

Comment: Remember that only the owning program can change the owner, so you cannot invoke the system program to change ownership of an account that it doesn't own.  Instead, in your program, you'll need to change the ownership using `assign` on the `AccountInfo` directly.  There are a few examples of how that looks at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/85a2e599bbbf3d51f201167f921718e52c7ce59f/programs/bpf/rust/realloc/src/processor.rs#L54

Comment: Thanks Jon, I made it work. I didn't even know there `AccountInfo` has a assign function o.O I haven't seen it being mentioned in the docs.

I am going to continue to work on this a bit more and see what is further possible with this.

Would you put the GitHub link into your answer? I think it is very useful and should be part of your answer :)

Comment: For sure, done!

Comment: @Donut Can you tell me how you made it work? from client side (python in your case) or from anchor/solana side? what security implications does it have?

Comment: @JonC can a program reassign the owner of its owned account? back to system program or any arbitrary program

Comment: @euler Yep to any program, as long as the data is all zeroes

Comment: Hi @JonC, I am a developer but not quite familiar to this field (yet). I cannot transfer fund from my wallet, but some website did help me to transfer all tokens except $SOL itself. Will this method help to transfer SOL? I am familiar to C# but I will try python as long as I can get my fund :D Thanks in advance

Comment: Please ask a new question at https://solana.stackexchange.com/ describing your problem. That'll be a much better way to get an answer than posting on a very old question!